# AngularJS Get Single Model Record For Editing In Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This seems like it should be easy to do but after googling around I haven't been able to find an exact answer.  I'm new to Angular so maybe it is just that I don't know how to ask the right question.

Problem:  I have a table that I'm filling with rows of data using `ng-repeat`.  This is pretty straight forward.  However, each row has an edit button that when pressed, launches a popup window where the data can be edited.  So, for it to be edited the popup window's form needs to be pre-loaded with corresponding row's data.  Then, of course, the pages model should be updated when the popup's save button is clicked.

Simply put, on click I want to open a popup with a form that is pre-filled with the data from a single row from my model.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's Modal.

My HTML:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th><th>Business Functions</th><th>Description</th><th>Retention Period</th><th>Examples</th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="record in InformationManagementRecords | filter:query">
            <td>{{record.RecordNumber}}</td>
            <td>{{record.ActivitiesCategoryName}}</td>
            <td>{{record.BusinessFunction}}</td>
            <td>{{record.ActivitiesCategoryDescription}}</td>
            <td>{{record.OfficialRetention}}</td>
            <td>{{record.TransactionExampleRecords}}</td>
            <td class="driverButtonsColumn">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" title="Edit" ng-click="setModalData(record)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEditModal"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice how my button has a `ng-click="setModalData(record)"` on it.  In an attempt to solve this problem I've created a function in my controller that returns a single record, it works but I can't seem to access the data when that function runs but again, maybe I'm doing it wrong.

My Controller:

```
var InfoManagementControllers = angular.module('InfoManagementControllers', []);

InfoManagementControllers.controller('InfoManagementCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get('api/InformationManagement').success(function (data) {
        $scope.InformationManagementRecords = data;

        $scope.setModalData = function (record) {
            $scope.modalData = record;
        }
    });
}]);
```

I hope this is enough information.

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: will have an easier time using angular-ui directives for bootstrap. Easy to pass data to modalController  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  You would select record the same way you are doing, but have form scope in modalController

Comment: I have the AngularUI modal working.  The only problem I have now is getting the data that I've edited in the modal to update the data on the page.  The examples provided in the AngularUI aren't quite what I'm looking for.  The example is sending data back to the page but not updating the page's model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the object like this:

```
$scope.setModalData = function(record) {
    $scope.record_to_edit = angular.copy(record);
}
```

Created a fiddle example showing copy vs. clone:

http://jsfiddle.net/robrothe/Fqfg3/

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite see what you are doing here. Can you provide more info?

Comment: I guess I don't see why you'd make a deep copy.  Why not just use the "record" itself?  For fun I put in your code just like you have it here and it didn't change anything as far as I could tell.  I still had the same problems.  So, this answer is probably incomplete.

Comment: Well, you don't have to make a deep copy, however, if you're just cloning the object, and you make a change and cancel the update, then the initial object will have the unwanted changes applied to it.

I made a fiddle example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fqfg3/